# Nested if statements does not go further then 2 times

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have a satiation where I need to make sure that my gauges on javafx runlater thread  are created to assign a value to it and avoid NullPointerException. so I have created multiple if statements that make the normal Thread sleeps until runlater thread finished, because the guage is created on another thread.

My problem is that program only enters first and second if statement and ignore the rest of them which cause a NullPointerException when assigning the value.

```
if (TDSgauge == null || TDNgauge == null) {

            t1.sleep(500);
            System.out.println("in 1 ------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            if (TDSgauge == null) {
                t1.sleep(500);
                System.out.println("in 2 ------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            }
            if (TDNgauge == null) {
                    t1.sleep(500);
                    System.out.println("in 3 ------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            }if (TDSgauge == null) {
                        t1.sleep(500);
                        System.out.println("in 4 ------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            }if (TDSgauge == null || TDNgauge == null) {
                            t1.sleep(500);
            System.out.println("in 5 ------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            }
        }
```

gauge creation has a long code, is it possible that when starting to create the gauge; gauge become not null?

Comment: I tried to give a helpful answer - but I have the feeling that we would need a real [mcve] in order to give correct guidance.

Comment: Beyond that - a bit of feedback would be welcome. Or you simply accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong approach.

First of all: don't duplicate code like this -  don't write down 5 nested if statements. If at all - use a loop that runs for a defined number of times making this check.

But that would still be a hack. Normally you would rather use wait() / notify(). Meaning: you use the built-in signaling mechanism of Java so that the waiting thread gets notified at some point. You build a way so that the waiting part gets a shoulder tap when it the condition to wait for is met.

On the other hand you absolutely do not want to sleep/wait  on the main event dispatcher thread. So you would need to show more of your code for better advice.